# arrayindexoutofbounds tag is too specific

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, retag-request, synonym-request

There is a [indexoutofboundsexception](/questions/tagged/indexoutofboundsexception) and [arrayindexoutofbounds](/questions/tagged/arrayindexoutofbounds). Their tag wiki's are obviously an almost copy but the language of [indexoutofboundsexception](/questions/tagged/indexoutofboundsexception) is general enough to encompass the second and it says it's intent is to be language-independent

I'm not sure about the usefulness of having these tags but I have no problem leaving them on, so I submit this to the audience:

Should these tags stay or go?

If the answer is stay then I think [arrayindexoutofbounds](/questions/tagged/arrayindexoutofbounds) is too specific and needs to be merged and made a synonym.

Comment: Created synonym... Didn't merge, in case something bad happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say keep them but make [arrayindexoutofbounds](/questions/tagged/arrayindexoutofbounds) a synonym of [indexoutofboundsexception](/questions/tagged/indexoutofboundsexception), indeed. After all, we have [whole list of exception tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/*exception) to match.

These two tags are mostly used combined with Java (and a small percentage of C#), but the former wins as it has the larger number of questions.

I'd do it right now but lack the required 5 votes in the tag..